# Excel Keeping Master-Child Worksheets in sync

Tags: excel

I have an Excel workbook that contains a master worksheet of all requests in a table. I source the main columns of that table (Request #, Request Title, and Department) to child worksheets within the same workbook.

These child worksheets have their own columns that correspond to the requests.  e.g. one sheet has hourly estimates, another sheet has what phase the request is in, etc.

I am having a hard time keeping the rows in sync across all 3 sheets.  Every time I insert, delete or move rows around in the master table, the other columns in the child spreadsheets move around and do not stay with their sourced columns.

How do I solve this problem?

Master Table
A, B, C

Child Sheet #1
A, B, C sourced from master
D only on child sheet

Child Sheet #2
A, B, C sourced from master
D only on child sheet

Comment: Select all tabs when you insert/delete rows.

Comment: I don't have Insert as an option if I select more than 1 Tab at a time.